# How to get syslogd and/or Apache2 to STOP logging DEBUG messages to console

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, rsyslog, syslog

When I SSH into one of my Linux boxes (Ubuntu 20.04.2), I periodically see messages appear on the console screen:

*Message from syslogd@my-hostname at Jan 30 21:35:17 ...
apache2: [MY-APP] DEBUG - 2024-01-30T13:35:17-08:00 - 0 -* : (extensive debug log info here)

The messages are ALWAYS "from syslogd@my-hostname" and ALWAYS include the "apache2: [MY-APP] DEBUG" string.

I have checked the usual Apache config settings:

/etc/apache2/ config files  <-- note that "LogLevel" in apache2.conf is set to "warn"

..and have looked at the /etc/syslog / rsyslogd config files as well and don't see anything that seems to explain this.

What are some other things I could check to determine how 'syslogd' is printing apache DEBUG messages to the console when Apache is configured with a LogLevel of "warn"?

Comment: Can you please show your running apache config with `apache2ctl -S` and also `rsyslogd -N1`

Comment: $ sudo apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
$

Comment: $ sudo rsyslogd -N1
rsyslogd: version 8.2001.0, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: End of config validation run. Bye.
$